# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.ag.h()

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services, crashlytics

We are getting a lot of readException crashes through Crashlytics lately for an Android app which has already been published. The only thing we're using from GooglePlayServices is Google Analytics
(compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0').
Since nullpointerexception is thrown within google play services library, it is quite difficult to detect why it is happening.

Any clue what is going on and how can we fix it?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzh.zzqv(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqx(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4917)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.ag.h()' on a null object reference
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The error happens within a google play services library, not within our code, so it is not something we could fix with detecting nullpointer within our code.

Comment: Can you share your app level build.gradle file. At least the dependencies.

Comment: it seems that the crash does not occur any more with the latest google play services update